# Appended '= x' after a method declaration in c++

Tags: c++, syntax, language-features

In C++, when a method is declared, I've noticed that sometime the method may have an assignement appended to it.

Could anyone tell me what this is?

For example:

```
virtual void MyMethod () = 0;
```

What doe the '= 0' mean. :)

Thanks everyone !!!

Comment: I think you mean C++...

Comment: C# is just C++ with the streams crossed.  (Don't cross the streams)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why pure virtual function is initialized by 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156634/why-pure-virtual-function-is-initialized-by-0)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm understanding it as working like an abstract method that must be overriden (implemented) in a subclass.

Comment: C++0x will introduce some new legal values of `x` other than `0`: `delete` to specify that a function doesn't exist (to remove a default constructor or assignment operator, or to prevent an implicit conversion) and `default` to explicitly specify the default implementation of a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means it's a pure virtual function, i.e. no actual definition of it is available in this class and it **must** be overridden in a subclass. It's not actually an assignment as such, zero is the only value you can "assign".

And this is C++ syntax; in C# the same would be accomplished with the `abstract` keyword.

Comment: This is assuming the OP meant C++, which he probably did. In C# the equivalent to this would be marking the method `abstract` and not giving it a body.

Comment: Not even any zero value will hold. *Only `0` is valid here*, it's put straight as a grammar symbol. `0L` or something else won't work. I.e while it may work on some compilers to use `NULL` instead (because it expands to `0` for them), on others it may not work :)

Comment: The bit about no definition isn't necessarily true. Rather, it just means a derived class needs to implement the function. If it is not, it cannot be instantiated.

Comment: GMan is correct.  Even if you make your destructor pure virtual you still need to provide a definition for it.  Pure virtual means that the function must be defined in any subclass before that subclass can be instantiated.

Comment: @GMan, @Bill, isn't that exactly what I said?

Comment: @calmh: No, you still claim that "no actual definition is available". Bill even came up with an example in which an actual definition _must_ be available.

Comment: Ah the "destructor" part, I missed that. True.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ this means that the method is a pure virtual method.

This means that an instance of this particular class-type cannot be instantiated. You can only create instances of classes derived from this, which override all pure virtual methods in the base class.

A base class with pure virtual methods defines an interface that derived classes *have* to implement, and is not meant to be used on its own.

---

Contrary to what calmh claims, as far as I know pure virtual functions *can* be implemented and they can be called explicitly.

```
#include <cstdio>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const = 0; //pure virtual
};

void A::foo() const { puts("A::foo"); }

class B: public A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const { puts("B::foo"); }
};

int main()
{
    //A a;  //this would be an error - main point of having pure virtual functions
    B b;
    b.foo();
    b.A::foo();
}
```

Usually one wouldn't do this, though, except perhaps if the virtual destructor is pure in a base class (in this case it has to be defined).

Comment: Also, (now, i'm entering a bit pedantry mode) contrary to what he writes, any subclass can leave off overriding it. It will then also be abstract, but if no-one creates an object of it (except as a base class subobject in turn), that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, that is a syntax error.

If you meant C++, see calmh's answer.