# What does "= 0" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why pure virtual function is initialized by 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156634/why-pure-virtual-function-is-initialized-by-0)

Hi all..

First off, I know that you declare a pure virtual method like this in C++:

```
virtual void myMethod() = 0;
```

.. but as I couldn't sleep last night, my nerdy head came to think if the "= 0"-part has any semantic meaning, or if it's "just" there to be able to declare purely virtual methods.

Are there any other places where this construct is used?
(And no - int v = 0; doesn't count :P )

Comment: Duplicate of [Why pure virtual function is initialized by 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156634/why-pure-virtual-function-is-initialized-by-0)

Comment: Nice find. SO really needs a better search feature (Or I need to be better at using it :) )

Comment: I wouldn't have found it if it wasn't already in my memory. Brain cache wasn't flushed yet.

Answer (score 4):

It'as a virtual pure method.

That means that :

- we don't provide the implementation (there is a way to provide one but it's not useful)
- we want the child class to implement this method
- we make this class impossible to instantiate : only a fully implemented child class can be

Comment: The OP did already know that.

Answer (score 0):

It means that method is pure virtual. So, the subtypes must implement it. Also, it doesn't have the implementation here and the class is not instantiable.