# What does "= 0;" do when declaring pure virtual functions in C++?

Tags: c++, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why pure virtual function is initialized by 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156634/why-pure-virtual-function-is-initialized-by-0)

I know that, in order to declare a pure virtual function you need to use "= 0;" syntax, like so:

```
class Foo  
{
protected:
    Foo();
    virtual int getValue() = 0;
};
```

My question is, what exactly (in the internal workings of the compiler) does the "= 0;" syntax do? Does it actually set the function pointer equal to zero? Does it serve as nothing more than a statement of intent, like the "abstract" reserved word in Java and C#, and if so, why not add a reserved word such as "abstract" to the language rather than using such arcane syntax?

Comment: This question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156634/why-pure-virtual-function-is-initialized-by-0).

Comment: Because the `pure` keyword would be too readable for C++ programmers.

Comment: @nightcracker: Bjarne Stroustrup is wary of contextual keywords (ie, identifiers that are only keywords in some contexts and not others) and rightly so because it makes lexing a bit more difficult (ie you cannot say whether a particular identifier is a keyword or not without its context). I cannot blame it for this. However he is also wary about introducing full keywords, and this yields all those weird usages (`static` !!!!).

Comment: @MatthieuM. C++11 does have some contextual keywords, though :)

Comment: Syntax has no inherent meaning. Just because two syntactic constructs look somewhat similar does *not* imply that they also have similar semantics.

Comment: @FredOverflow: yes "for the sake of backward compatibility". Having seen (and attempted to understand) the lexer code in Clang, with its weird plugs for semantic disambiguation, I can say it is a mess :x

Answer (score 1):

It declares a 'pure virtual' function.  The = 0 is *basically* like another 'pure' keyword.  This question is related to yours: [Why is a pure virtual function initialized by 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156634/why-pure-virtual-function-is-initialized-by-0)

A pure virtual function has no body at all and must be defined by any classes which inherit it: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/126-pure-virtual-functions-abstract-base-classes-and-interface-classes/

Answer (score 0):

That signifies that there is no "default" implementation. Any derived class needs to implement it.

Comment: Note that pure virtual functions can have implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It forces you to define it in a child class.