# why virtual void test()=00 is valid but virtual void test()=+0 and virtual void test()=-0 is not valid?

Tags: c++, syntax

I searched some post about virtual function declaration, which believed

```
=0
```

in

```
virtual void test()=0;
```

is fixed syntex so

```
virtual void test()=NULL;
virtual void test()=false;
virtual void test()=1-1;
virtual void test()=0.0;
```

and other declarations should not be valid.

but I found

```
virtual void test()=00;
virtual void test()=000;
virtual void test()=0000;
```

can also compile, why?

and also, I think integer +0 and -0 are actually same as 0 (I am not sure if it is right), just like 00 is actually 0, why

```
virtual void test()=+0;
```

and

```
virtual void test()=-0;
```

cannot compile?

Comment: If `=00;` compiles, file a bug with your compiler's developers.

Comment: Very similar to [Pure virtual functions in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20861346/1708801)

Comment: gcc 4.9.2 correctly reports "error: invalid pure specifier (only '= 0' is allowed) before ';' token".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [November 2014 working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) of the standard:

10.4:

> A virtual function is specified pure by using a pure-specifier (9.2)
> in the function declaration in the class definition.

In 9.2 we see the definition of a "pure-specifier":

> pure-specifier:
> = 0

This shows that your examples should not compile, as you expect and as such you should file a bug report with your compiler manufacturer.

Answer (score 4):

The *pure-specifier* is the exact token sequence `= 0` - two tokens, `=` and `0`, in that order.

No other token is allowed. A compiler that accepts `=00` without (at the very least) a warning is non-conforming.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is simply because compiler (or some pre-compilation process) is replacing set of zeros with single zero. Excel and Calc.exe, for example replaces `0000` with `0`.