# Error: cannot convert 'double' to 'double(double, double, double)' in assignment

Tags: c++, string, double, cmath

I know my work is sloppy, this is my 4th assignment in this class. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
double  getPrincipal(0);
double  getRate(0);
double  getYears(0);
double  computeAmount(double getPrincipal, double getRate, double getYears);
double  displayAmount(double principal, double rate, double years, double amount);

cout << "what is the principal ammount?" << endl;
cin >> getPrincipal;

cout << "What is the percentage rate?" << endl;
cin >> getRate;

cout << "Over how many years will the money stay in the bank?" << endl;
cin >> getYears;  

computeAmount = pow((1 + getRate / 100),getYears); // This is where i got the error
```

Comment: Did you mean to declare/use lambda functions in this code block?

Answer (score 3):

You are messing up **`functions`** with **`variables`** by trying to assign a value to a function.

```
double  computeAmount(double getPrincipal, double getRate, double getYears);
```

By this line, you declare `computeAmount()` to be a function who takes 3 `double`s as its parameters and return a `double`.

But, in this line,

```
computeAmount = pow((1 + getRate / 100),getYears);
```

You're trying to use it as a variable.

Depends on what your purpose is, you may want to change one of these two lines. For example, you can delete the first line, and change the second line to:

```
double computeAmount = pow((1 + getRate / 100),getYears);
```

Comment: _'You can't assign a value to a function.'_ Well, actually you can: `virtual void foo() = 0;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is not an assignment, but a syntactical way of specifying a pure virtual function.

Comment: @ZacHowland You can actually use values other than `0` (and there are even reasonable use cases for this).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you mean `= delete` or `= default`, yes, but again, those are not assignment, but simply syntax for [stating information about the function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2156723/529761).  You cannot write `virtual void foo() = 1;` - it will not compile.

Comment: @ZacHowland No I meant s.th. like `virtual void foo() = 0x00000f24;`. You can use it to bind certain ROM addresses on bare metal environments. Seen that, been there ... May be a compiler specific extension though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is not [standard compliant](http://ideone.com/Cgy5PD).  The `= 0` notation is not *assigning* the function to 0, it is stating the function is not there.  Stroustrup went with that syntax instead of trying to fight with people over adding a new keyword.  In effect, `= 0` (when used in this context) is really just a keyword stating the function is a pure virtual function (and prior to C++11, `0` was the only valid token after the `=`.  C++11 added `default` and `delete` to the list).

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler is trying to tell you, you can't assign a variable to a function

If you want that to be a function, define it & call it.

If you want it to be a variable, declare it as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

`computeAmount` is the name of a function you defined that returns a `double` and takes 3 `double` parameters.  `pow` returns a `double`.

Change that line to

```
double computedAmount = pow((1 + getRate) / 100, getYears);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- notice this is no longer the function name, but a new variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared name `computeAmount` as a function name

```
double  computeAmount(double getPrincipal, double getRate, double getYears);
```

So this statement

```
computeAmount = pow((1 + getRate / 100),getYears);
```

has no sense. As `computeAmount` is a function name then in the espression above it is converted to pointer to function and you are trying to assign some double value returned by function `pow` to this pointer.

Answer (score 1):

computeAmount is declared as a function, but used on the left-hand side of '=' operator.
Solution:  Re-declare computeAmount as just a double:

```
double computeAmount;
```