# What is the meaning of "Type Qualifier (const)" after function name in function declaration declaration(virtual void printMarksheet() const = 0;)?

Tags: c++

I have happened to read a function definition like this:

```
virtual void printMarksheet() const = 0;
```

I thought initially that the syntax may be incorrect. So I wrote a dummy code to check. I wrote the following code and compiled. It compiled successfully. But I would like to know the meaning of the line. Is it function definition? or function declaration? What is the significance of const=0.

```
class Marksheet
        {
        public:
            virtual void printMarksheet() const = 0;
        };
        int main()
        {
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why pure virtual function is initialized by 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156634/why-pure-virtual-function-is-initialized-by-0)

Comment: That question gives only a partial answer to my question @Levi.

Answer (score 0):

Its a function declaration. `const=0` are two different things. By defining `const`, the function will not be able to change the data member value. By defining `=0`, the function declared as pure virtual function.